# Как изменить Json запись C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, backend

Как изменить Json запись типа

```
{
"Id" : 1,
"Active" : True
}
```

Хочу изменить "Active" : True на False

Newtonsoft C#

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что этот json прилетает в контроллер сайта на asp.net core (судя по меткам), а потому вполне возможно сделать так, чтобы уже прилетало в нужный класс (FromBody).

Answer (score 1):

На раз-два-три:

- Распарсить в объект
- Поменять свойства объекта
- Заново сериализовать в строку

В коде это будет примерно так:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = this.GetSample();
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(source);
    deserialized.Active = false;

    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialized, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    //result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public string GetSample()
{
    return  "{ 'Id': 1, 'Active': true }";
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё. Ваш json невалиден: `True` - некорректное значение для булева типа, правильно `true`.

- [Json.Net boolean parsing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19010892/5752652)